# Uncaught Error: Unable to convert "undefined" into a date (Angular)

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, angular-calendar

In this example, I want to get all bookings data from a service and push them to an array CalendarEvent[]. But I received this error `Uncaught Error: Unable to convert "undefined" into a date`. I assumed that something is wrong with my service?

ng-calendar.component.ts:

```
export class NgCalendarComponent {
  events: CalendarEvent[] = [];
  bookings: any = {};
  date: string;

  constructor(private bookingService: BookingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookings = this.bookingService.getAllBookings();

    for (let booking of this.bookings) {
      var b = this.bookings[booking];
      this.date = formatDate(b.bookDate, 'medium', 'en-us', 'GMT+8');

      this.events.push({
        start: new Date(this.date),
        title: b.purpose,
      });
    }
  }
```

booking.service.ts:

```
export class BookingService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllBookings() {
    return this.http.get('/api/bookings/')
      .pipe(map(response => response));
  }
}
```

BookingResource.cs:

```
public class BookingResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public RoomResource Room { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePairResource Building { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookDate { get; set; }
    public ContactResource Contact { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeSlotResource> TimeSlots { get; set; }

    public BookingResource()
    {
        TimeSlots = new Collection<TimeSlotResource>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a console.log(this.booking) to see what the answer looks like

Comment: you need to handle null check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAllBooking()` returns an observable, you have to subscribe to it to get the result. Or convert it to a promise :

```
  async getAllBookings() {
    return this.http.get('/api/bookings/').toPromise();
  }
```

And call it like this :

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.bookings = await this.bookingService.getAllBookings();
    ...
```

Comment: it now returns booking objects. do you know how to iterate over all those booking objects and get their values to be pushed into events[ ]? it returns this error if I try to iterate.

Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.bookings is not iterable

sorry, i'm new to javascript and typescript.. so far i've been coding in java and c#..

Comment: One problem at a time, Uncaught in promise means exactly what it says, you first should catch the error, see what it says, then go from there.

Comment: I ran error handling and it says 'TypeError: this.bookings is not iterable'

Comment: my mistake, i forgot to update the Bookings api. thank you @Noelmout.. I will learn more.